# Using seaborn, how can I add a data point of a different color to my scatterplot or change to color of last data point?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)
    grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")
```

The above code will create the scatter plot based on the Iris data set. I want to add another data point at [3,.05] that will be red in color; or make the last point within the data set red in color. How do I go about doing this?

[image: My current Image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To add a point at custom `x` and `y` coordinates**, add [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) with your coordinates:

```
plt.scatter(x=3, y=0.5, color='r')
```

And **to color your last point**, use the [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) locator on your data:

```
plt.scatter(iris.petal_length.iloc[-1], iris.petal_width.iloc[-1], color='r')
```

**Note** that the `iloc` locator is from `pandas`, and `plt.scatter` is from `matplotlib.pyplot`. Both of these are mandatory dependencies of seaborn, so you definitely have them on your machine if you're using seaborn.

For example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")    
grid = sns.JointGrid(iris.petal_length, iris.petal_width, space=0, size=6, ratio=50)
grid.plot_joint(plt.scatter, color="g")
# add your point
plt.scatter(x=3, y=0.5, color='r')
# or
# plt.scatter(iris.petal_length.iloc[-1], iris.petal_width.iloc[-1], color='r')
```

[image]

Comment: I add marginal plots as well with the following code;  "grid.plot_marginals(sns.distplot, kde=False, color=".5")". How would I a blue line mark the last datapoint of x, y respectively to the distribution plots?

Comment: As for the line on the `distplot`s, I'd recommend asking a separate question, I don't have the answer off the top of my head, and it's a different issue